Nextjs routing giving 404 this page could not be found
I have an app directory with the following pages:
/app
layout.tsx
page.tsx
portfolio.tsx

app/admin
layout.tsx
page.tsx
settings.tsx

I am able to access page.tsx on both app and admin but I am unable to access portfolio and settings.tsx
app/admin/page.tsx
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full p-5">
        <Navbar />
        <main className="w-full flex flex-col py-4 max-w-5xl pb-6">
          <Link href="/admin/settings">
            <a className="mt-5 rounded-lg py-3 text-center w-full bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold mb-5">
              Setting Page
            </a>
          </Link>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;

app/admin/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "../globals.css";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}


Can you update the file structure as follows:
/app
  layout.tsx
  page.tsx
  /portfolio
    page.tsx

/app/admin
  layout.tsx
  page.tsx
  /settings
    page.tsx

Note: You need to create additional portfolio and settings folders, and place the content of your existing portfolio.tsx and settings.tsx files inside the newly created page.tsx files within these folders.
For reference, this Next.js documentation might help as well: Next.js File Conventions
